# HDInsight deployment automation from scratch with .pfx certificate

Tags: azure, deployment, automation, azure-hdinsight

When an HDInsight cluster is created in Azure, `ADLS` can be selected as the primary storage. It needs a *service principal* to authenticate the `HDInsight` to `ADLS`, and this can be generated and the *certificate/key* downloaded as a `.pfx` file in step 2. Azure explicitly states that the file must be downloaded and kept safe if the cluster needs to be recreated. (*In step 2 the second option is to use an existing principal, where the .pfx must be uploaded.)* So far so good - everything works as expected.

The problem is that I need to automate the whole process. I downloaded the Azure RM deployment template. In this file, one has to specify the `identityCertificate`, which is already existing `.pfx` file. I could not find the way to generate it with the template deployment.

What we tried is to create a service principal, store it in the key vault, and download the certificate with the following Azure CLI commands:

```
az ad sp create-for-rbac --name ${sp_name} --create-cert --keyvault ${vault} --cert ${cert_name}
az keyvault certificate download --vault-name ${vault} --name ${cert_name} --file ${cert_name}.pem
```

The problem is that the `.pem` file created this way contains only the public key, and the deployment fails.

Obviously, I cannot tell our client that they need to click here and there in Azure to create the cluster when the product goes live. So the main question is:

**How can I create such a service principal and get the `.pfx` programmatically in order to be able to deploy HDInsight ?**

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to create a complete certificate. I accidentally found an example under the `az keyvault certificate import` documentation.

The point is that if `az ad sp create-for-rbac` is invoked without the key vault option, it generates the key pair and stores it locally. The file path can be extracted from the output (JSON by default, the global query parameters work here just fine).

So the snippet that made the trick:

```
gen_cert_file=$(az ad sp create-for-rbac --name ${sp_name} --create-cert --query fileWithCertAndPrivateKey --output tsv)
mv ${gen_cert_file} ./${cert_file}
openssl pkcs12 -export -in ${cert_file} -passout "pass:${cert_pass}" -out ${pfx_file}
az keyvault certificate import --vault-name ${keyvault_name} --name ${cert_name} --file ${pfx_file} --password "${cert_pass}"
```

The result of the first command is a .pem file. It is converted to a password-protected .pfx file with the `openssl` tool. This file can equally be used in the Azure console or in a deployment template.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a github project, that gives template to deploy a new Linux HDInsight cluster with new Data Lake Store and Storage accounts

Also PowerShell script to generate Certificate (PFX) file and service principal creation

https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/201-hdinsight-datalake-store-azure-storage